# after submit form using ajax load url , jquery datepicker not work

Tags: jquery, load, datepicker, ajaxform

i have some problem here..when in page (addisy.php which is have jquery datepicker and its work well.) i submit my form using ajaxForm. after submitting,the page has loaded the main page which is name as isylist.php. then, if i click again the addisy.php, the jquery datepicker not working anymore..can stackoverflow member help me where in the code was error or conflict??

my code is here :
addisy.php

```
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="json/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script>
         var j = $.noConflict();
         (function() {
         j('#isyform').ajaxForm({
           success: function(xhr) {
          },
         complete: function(xhr) {
             alert(xhr.responseText);
              $('#frame').load('isylist.php');
                 }
             }); 
             })();

       </script>

     <div id="frame">
       <form action="saveisy.php" method="post" id="isyform">
       <input type="text" id="datecollected" name="datecollected" class="datepicker" />
        <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datecollected").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "d-m-yy"
        });
      });

      </script>
      <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Save" />
       </form>
       </div>
```

Comment: why you are using `$` and `j`? Try with either `$` or `j`.

Comment: i used j and $ to differentiate jquery ajax form and jquery datepicker  because it will conflict between jquery if use same $.

Comment: AFAIK, it will not conflict until unless if we use different jquery versions. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: i already try use the same $.. but the datepicker not display at all..it means it conflict. thats why i use j and $.

Comment: the datepicker i use version 1.9.1. and ajax form i use 1.7.

Comment: can you share url if you have?

Comment: what do you mean? i dont get it...sorry for my bad english..

Comment: url where you deployed the above mentioned code.

Comment: i dont have the url...so i cant share it with you.